# Javascript Promises wait for two async methods to complete

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following where the first services *serviceDefinitionFactory.getServices* call calls a REST api and gets some data **in an array**. It then maps its array to a *var services*

*services* is then the parameter passed that is *maped* to the next REST api services call
which is *serviceDefinitionFactory.getMethods*.

I get the data in the array from the first services call, but I don't get the data from the next, I'm not waiting on the promise.

Here's my poor attempt, this code is in an angular 1.5 controller btw.

```
    function test (){      
        var serviceObject = {service: null, methods: null};
        var store = [];

        serviceDefinitionFactory.getServices().then( function(srvs){
            var services = srvs.data.map(function(service) {
                return ServiceFactory(service, 'trigger');
            })
            var params = {kind :"trigger" };
            services.map(function(service) {
                    serviceDefinitionFactory.getMethods(service, params).then(function(values){
                        serviceObject.service = service;
                        serviceObject.methods = values;
                        store.push(serviceObject);
                        })   
                })
            })
         console.log("ALL PROMISES RESOLVED = " + store.length);
         return store; 
     }
```

My problem is I don't understand how to pass the parameter from the first call to the second, then wait for the accumulated result. The duplicate link marked by Felix assumes no parameter passing. Apologies for being stupid, but I'm stuck

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Both promises arent' resolved where you log it out. Both promises are resolved where you do store.push (inside the second then)

Comment: I've followed the duplicate link, but my problem is that the 2nd call is dependant on a parameter from the 1st. I can execute two methods where the second is not dependant on the first's return value

Comment: Felix, why is this duplicate ? I'm asking about chaining two calls where the first provides a parameter to the second. The link you provided  assumes no parameters.

Comment: see where you `return store`? `store` will be empty because promises don't make asynchronous code synchronous

Comment: also, where `serviceObject` is declared guarantees issues

Comment: as the question is closed, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4q7L5u9/) with possibly some insight

Comment: Jaromanda X: Thank you so much for taking the time to code up the Fiddle, it's working